# Requesting an authorization code through a backchannel

Tags: oauth-2.0, openiddict

According to the OAuth2.0 spec and the way it is implemented in OpenIddict 3.1.1, an authorization code should be retrieved by performing a GET request to the authorization endpoint. This will then redirect the user to a login page (if needed) and ask for explicit authorization from the user.

It is, however, also possible to configure a client application to use an implicit consent type, where the user does not need to explicitly give permission to the application.

My question builds on this: If I know that the user is already signed in (I have a valid access token), would it be possible to request an authorization code for a different application through a backchannel POST request (using the authorization header to specify that I have access to do this) instead of having to go through the browser for this flow?

As far as I can see in OpenIddct 3.1.1, the authorization code is generated in some middleware that handles signin results. This seems to make it difficult for me to generate such an authorization code in a custom endpoint designed for my desired scenario mentioned above.

The reason I'm wondering about this at all is because I'm building a desktop application for which I'll open a browser for the initial login, but after that I need to request an authorization code for a custom server back-end and I'd prefer not having to open the browser once more just for this purpose, since I know the user is authenticated (and authorized) to request this authorization code anyway. I would of course send the all the required information in this backchannel POST request (client_id, code_challenge, challenge_method, scopes...)

**EDIT:**

The reason I need a second access token is because:

I have 4 systems:

- Desktop application
- Custom Server
- Resource Server
- Identity Provider

The desktop application is the one that is directly used by the user, and it will request an access token through the regular auth_code flow from the Identity Provider. This desktop application will then request resources in the resource API, for which it needs an access token. This process is working as standard.

Now I also want the Custom Server application to request resources from the resource server. Normally you would use client credentials for this, because it is server to server, but the resources are owned by the user, so I'd want an access token specifically for these resources.

For this I now start a second auth_code flow on the desktop application to request an authorization code for the Custom Server. I then send this auth_code back to the Custom Server, which exchanges it for an access token. This works, but I would prefer if I didn't have to start a full on auth_code flow on the desktop application for this second process, as I know that the user is authorized to request this auth_code, and the consent type for the Custom Server is implicit in this case.

Comment: Why would you need an authorization code for the back-end? Your access token should be enough, not?

Comment: Good question, I guess I didn't make that clear enough. I added an explanation to my question above.